# Use .htaccess to rewrite address from xxx.example.com to example.com/xxx/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am looking for a way so that users can access their page by typing `xxx.example.com` and are then forwarded to their respective WordPress post.

Now I already have two rewrite functions on my site: (not written by me)

To use https everywhere:

```
 #Rewrite everything to https
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

And the WordPress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now, that WordPress function seems to translate `example.com/post_title` to the corresponding post.

But how do I rewrite it so it translates `post_title.example.com` to the corresponding post?

And if possible, still showing the `xxx.example.com` instead of `example.com/xxx`

Comment: Nobody that knows, or isn't it possible?

Comment: Well. Domain.com would open the root and xxx.domain.com would access the directory xxx in the domain.com.


Or I'm a getting it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, change your `.htaccess` to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

# This rewrite rule will only be used if
# we have an empty query string and the http host does not start with www
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [L]

# The default wordpress rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

For this to work I guess you need to setup a correct permalink structure in your wordpress installation:

[image]

Comment: @Jerry - Did you try this?

Comment: Funny, I actually just had time to sit down, going to test it now.. .

Comment: The first one (without the virtual host (no idea what that is)) caused a loop when connecting to the main site..

Comment: Having issue with www
While trying to access site.com it will try to open site.com/www

Comment: @Jerry - You can easily add a condition that takes care of the `www` part. I will update my answer.

Comment: Your answer is working for the "forward  subdomain to subdir" works..
But I found out that WordPress isn't really storing the posts in subdir, so I have no idea where, but you maybe know how to rewrite the WordPress rewrite? 

I mean that rewrite from WordPress must be the one that forwards from:   
Site.com/post  to where ever the posts are stored, is there anyway to change that rewrite to do so..

 dam, now I'm confused..
Maybe I should write a new question, and express the question correctly..

Maybe

Comment: @Jerry - Just update your question with the relevant information. Now I understand what you would like to do. Will make an update to my answer in a while.

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: @Jerry - I added a working solution which also keeps the first part in the url, so `post.site.com` will be rewritten to `post.site.com/post`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting a 500error.

I tried to remove everything except your part, the same problem..

Comment: Wait..a moment.

Comment: @Jerry - How have you configured your permalink structure in wordpress? What url are you trying to access when you get `500 - Internal Server Error`? The above is working fine for me running the latest wordpress version? Perhaps you made a mistake when pasting it into the `.htaccess` file? We could continue this in chat, since there is so much comments.

Comment: @Jerry - Pop into this chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/170671/wordpress-rewrite-rule?tab=general

Comment: Irc/msn?  Pop to gr1.se and "leave a comment" if you want via msn (don't suppose leaving email addresses here are good 

Comment: @Jerry - Nope I guess not. Add me on skype instead, my skypename is cyclonecode

Comment: Typical, and I don&#39;t have Skype..
Could download it thou.

Comment: Well just download and install it then?